RegionPlot does not work appropriately
I am trying to use RegionPlot to show acceptable values of parameters. I am using the code
RegionPlot[((-x/y) - 3 + x ) > 0, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.4, 0.4}, 
 FrameLabel -> {ε, λ}, PlotLabel -> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"(\",\nFontFamily->\"Courier New\",\nFontSize->36]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"a\",\nFontFamily->\"Courier New\",\nFontSize->36]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\")\",\nFontFamily->\"Courier New\",\nFontSize->36]\)", 
 TicksStyle -> Thick,  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 30], 
 RotateLabel -> True]

The problem is that the numbers that associated to ticks of axes are too large. The code "LabelStyle" controls both the size of these numbers and the size of label axes (lambda and epsilon). I would like to have labels with the same size but smaller ticks numbers.
Moreover, the code "RotateLabel" does not work.
Thank You for your time

If you are satisfied with an answer you should accept it by clicking
the check mark in the left column

Do you want this?
st = Sequence[Black, Bold, 30];

RegionPlot[((-x/y) - 3 + x) > 0, {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.4, 0.4},
 FrameLabel -> {Style[\[CurlyEpsilon], st], 
   Rotate[Style[\[Lambda], st], 3 Pi/2]},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Thick,
 PlotLabel -> Style["(a)", FontFamily -> "Courier New", st]]



Yes, I do. Thank you so much.

You're most welcome
